# Find the real numbers $x$ such that $\{x\} =\frac {x-3}{2\lfloor x\rfloor-5}.$

Tags: fractions, fractional-part

Determine the real numbers that verify the relation

$$\{x\} =\frac {x-3}{2\lfloor x\rfloor-5}$$

where $\{x\}$ represents the fractional part, respectively $\lfloor x\rfloor$ represents the whole part of the real number $x.$
I tried writing $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ or $\lfloor x \rfloor=x-\{x\} $  but I don't know what to do with them. I need a idea to start.

Thank you and I hope one of you can help me!

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Do you mean $\frac {x-3}{2[x]-5}$ or $x-\frac 3{2[x]-5}$.  Beyond that, graphing the thing might not be a bad start.

Comment: Sorry, i will edit it right now, its the first model...

Comment: Is it better???

Comment: Hint: let $\lfloor x\rfloor =k$ and solve for $x$. Then check if your solution fulfills $\lfloor x\rfloor =k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $f=x-n.$ Then,
$$\{x\} =\frac {x-3}{2\lfloor x\rfloor-5}\iff f=\frac{n+f-3}{2n-5}.$$

- If $f\ne\frac12,$ $$\begin{align}f(2n-5)=n+f-3&\iff2nf-5f=n+f-3\\&\iff2nf-n=5f+f-3\\&\iff n(2f-1)=6f-3\\&\iff n=\frac{6f-3}{2f-1}\\&\iff n=3.\end{align}$$
- $f=\frac12,$ $f(2n-5)=n+f-3.$

Hence the set of solutions is $[3,4)\cup(\Bbb Z+\frac12).$

Comment: I dont really understand what you did ?? Can you explain me in a more simple way plz???

Comment: Oooo...okey....the f and n got me in trouble....thank youu sooo much!!!!

Comment: With respect to [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), is the posted question of high enough quality to allow MathSE reviewers to answer?

Comment: Sorry, but i dont really understand how you get to the results that n=(6f-3)/(2f-1)

Comment: I did it on my way and i got that n=(n+6f-3)/(2f)

Comment: Both your equation and mine are nearly equivalent to 2nf=n+6f−3 but the "nearly" makes the difference: your equation is not valid if f=0. In mine, I excluded the case f=1/2, which I treated separately. I just added the details for mine

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{{x}\right\}=\frac{{x}−\mathrm{3}}{\mathrm{2}\lfloor{x}\rfloor−\mathrm{5}} \\ $$
$$\mathrm{2}\left\{{x}\right\}−\mathrm{1}=\frac{\mathrm{2}\left\{{x}\right\}−\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}\lfloor{x}\rfloor−\mathrm{5}} \\ $$
$$\left(\mathrm{2}\lfloor{x}\rfloor−\mathrm{6}\right)\left(\mathrm{2}\left\{{x}\right\}−\mathrm{1}\right)=\mathrm{0} \\ $$
$${x}=\left[\mathrm{3};\mathrm{4}\right)\cup\left({Z}+\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}}\right) \\ $$